# New Apple developer enrolment and app transfer

Tags: ios, apple-developer

I'm pretty new to iOS and app development as well. My question is how long does the enrollment process take for an organization's enrollment into the developer program? Also, I'd like to know how long it would take to transfer apps from a different enrollment to my new enrollment program?

I've searched the Apple support groups, but couldn't find a definitive answer.
I'm sure most of the iOS devs out here may have had these questions, and probably would be in a position to provide an answer.

Thank you.

Comment: Did the transfer accepted by the recipient organization’s Team Agent?

Comment: May be it will help you https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html

Comment: Before initiating the transfer, I wish to know. 
Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help...

Comment: Tried adding a new person in the same account and transfering the app, it worked. But I'm not sure if it'll work the same way if the transfer is between two enrollments.